# Set MainClass from jar to another Jar

Tags: java, gradle

I have a main.jar package that has another jar inside lib/my-jar.jar.

How do I set MainClass for main.jar so that it runs a class from lib/my-jar.jar package ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean `Main-Class` from the manifest, there is no simple way to refer to a class that is in a jar which is itself included in another jar.

What you can do is:

- Move `lib/my-jar.jar` outside your main jar and add it into your class path by setting `Class-Path` to `lib/my-jar.jar` in the manifest of your main jar.
- Or move/explode the content of `my-jar.jar` into your main jar

Answer (score 0):

Just import the class which is needed into you main class. The import will be resolved successfully as it is part of your jar and you can simply use the class after import.